# Mumps connectivity with java

Tags: java, database, connectivity, mumps

I want to script from MUMPS database using java. Can anyone suggest to me any connection string for it or any other way to connect it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970844/how-to-read-mumps-gt-m-database-using-java-application

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I think you want to connect to a MUMPS database using Java. Can you tell us which MUMPS database are you using?

Comment: These may help - https://github.com/search?q=Mumps+Java&type=Repositories